# Connection pool error in Rails application with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am having an issue when my Rails app is deployed in AWS ECS. Many of requests finish with `200` but there are some (every let's say 50) finish with `500`. The log says:

`ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool with 'primary' found.)`

I changed my pool (in `database.yml` config) to 15, also set RAILS_MAX_THREADS to 15, and indeed it happens rarely now but still the problem occurs.

What am I missing here?

Ruby version: 2.6.6
Postgres: 11.5

database.yml:

```
production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['DB_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DB_PORT'] %>
  pool: 25
```

Comment: care to share database.yml  please ?

Comment: Sorry I haven't done it before, the question is updated

Comment: Do you also the pg gem installed ?

Comment: Yes, it is installed

Comment: can you check out the yml I pasted below

Answer (score 1):

Try and use this have common values in default and then depending upon env have individual values for the other environments, which can be based on environment variables:

```
default: &default
  adapter:  postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  port:     <%= ENV.fetch("POSTGRESQL_PORT", "5432") %>
  pool:     <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_USER_NAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV.fetch("POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD", "somepassword") %>
  host:     <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_HOST'] %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_DB'] %>-development
  host: db

production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['POSTGRESQL_DB'] %>
```

Comment: Unfo the issue still persists.

Comment: Do you have any rake tasks running ?? If at all,  then it could be that you are not running environment task before you run your rake task, task some_task: : environment do end